# Azure Event Grid topic subscription with Service Bus queue handler

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-eventgrid

I'd like to set up an Event Grid Subscription for a topic with a Service Bus queue as the handler. The Service Bus queue lives in a separate subscription from the Event Grid topic; user accounts do not have standing access to both subscriptions. Therefore, I'm wondering if there is a way to configure the handler with the Service Bus connection string. Is this currently possible? Are there any work-arounds?

Comment: as a workaround can be used the *Azure Function* with output binding for Service Bus entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, the only way to directly do this is the user creating the Event Subscription must have permissions to write to the Service Bus queue, so you would have to grant at least that level of access.

Once Managed Service Identities lands in Event Grid for publishing, you'll be able to assign write access to the MSI and then direct Event Grid to use that MSI with the Event Subscription for publish.

Answer (score 0):

As Roman said, for such resources belonging to different subscriptions, you can use the Event Grid Trigger in Azure Function. You can configure the endpoint of the Event Grid topic subscription to an Azure Function, and then use this Azure Function to pass information to the Service Bus queue in another subscription.